# VS.NET "watched" objects and recursive depth

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In VS.NET, when you add an item to the watch, why is the base property often (always??) endlessly recursive?

Comment: Createa a new MVC project (with the default template), add a breakpoint somewhere in HomeController.Index and add a watch on "ViewData" - Expand the "Raw View" and "base" ad infinitum. This isn't an MVC issue, just the quickest example I could come up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still see this behavior in Visual Studio 2010? I remember seeing it on occasion in 2k8 and 2k5, but a cursory glance at my 2k10 projects show no such recursion on `base`. Sometimes they show many levels deep under `base` (in one instance 18) and it appears to be "recursive" only because the visible column is the `Value` column.